# Method-level tracing of Java-based application using Wily Introscope

Tags: java, performance, introscope

What I really want to know is that how do we do the method level tracing of a Java based application using Wily Introscope?I want to trace all the methods of all the class present in my application. Please help.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/alfredxiao/jackplay, which is exactly created to do method level tracing without code change or redeployment.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

`introscope.autoprobe.enable=true` in your IntroscopeAgent.properties file.  Then you will need to build a .pbd file for the class you want to monitoring.  It would look something like:

```
#Custom Instrumentation for YouApplication
SetTracerClassMapping: ProxyBlamePointTracer com.wily.introscope.agent.trace.hc2.BlamePointTracer com.wily.introscope.probebuilder.validate.ResourceNameValidator
SetTracerParameter: ProxyBlamePointTracer nameformatter com.wily.field.ParameterSubstringFormatter
SetTracerParameter: ProxyBlamePointTracer newmode true
SetTracerParameter: ProxyBlamePointTracer useblame true

SetTracerClassMapping: ProxyExceptionErrorReporter com.wily.introscope.agent.trace.hc2.MethodThrewErrorReportingTracer com.wily.introscope.probebuilder.validate.MetricNameValidator
SetTracerParameter: ProxyExceptionErrorReporter nameformatter com.wily.field.ParameterSubstringFormatter


SetFlag: YourAppTracing
TurnOn: YourAppTracing
IdentifyClassAs: abc.de.efg.hijk.lmnop YourAppTracing
IdentifyInheritedAs: abc.de.efg.hijk.lmnop YourAppTracing
TraceComplexMethodsIfFlagged: YourAppTracing ProxyBlamePointTracer "YourApp|SUB|{classname}|{method}"
TraceComplexMethodsIfFlagged: YourAppTracing ProxyExceptionErrorReporter "YourApp|SUB|{classname}|{method}:Errors Per Interval"
```